# How to solve Laravel 10 NextJS CORS Error

Tags: laravel, next.js, cors

I am using Laravel 10 for API and NextJS for frontend.

Please find the axios get request below;

```
export const getCategories = async (): Promise<IResult> => {
return new Promise<IResult>((resolve) => {
    axios.get("https://exampledomain.com/public/api/categories/"})
        .then((response) => {
            resolve(response.data);
        }).catch((error) => {
            resolve(error);
        })
})
}
```

Laravel 10 config/cors.php

```
<?php

return [

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) Configuration
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may configure your settings for cross-origin resource sharing
| or "CORS". This determines what cross-origin operations may execute
| in web browsers. You are free to adjust these settings as needed.
|
| To learn more: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS
|
*/

'paths' => ['api/*', 'sanctum/csrf-cookie'],

'allowed_methods' => ['*'],

'allowed_origins' => ['*'],

'allowed_origins_patterns' => [],

'allowed_headers' => ['*'],

'exposed_headers' => [],

'max_age' => 0,

'supports_credentials' => true,
];
```

Kernel.php

```
protected $middleware = [
    // \App\Http\Middleware\TrustHosts::class,
    \App\Http\Middleware\TrustProxies::class,
    \Illuminate\Http\Middleware\HandleCors::class,
    \App\Http\Middleware\PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance::class,
    \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize::class,
    \App\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings::class,
    \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull::class,
];

/**
 * The application's route middleware groups.
 *
 * @var array<string, array<int, class-string|string>>
 */
protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [
        \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
        \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
        \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
    ],

    'api' => [
        // \Laravel\Sanctum\Http\Middleware\EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful::class,
        \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class.':api',
        \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
    ],
];

/**
 * The application's middleware aliases.
 *
 * Aliases may be used instead of class names to conveniently assign middleware to routes and groups.
 *
 * @var array<string, class-string|string>
 */
protected $middlewareAliases = [
    'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
    'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
    'auth.session' => \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
    'cache.headers' => \Illuminate\Http\Middleware\SetCacheHeaders::class,
    'can' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
    'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
    'password.confirm' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\RequirePassword::class,
    'precognitive' => \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\HandlePrecognitiveRequests::class,
    'signed' => \App\Http\Middleware\ValidateSignature::class,
    'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
    'verified' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\EnsureEmailIsVerified::class,
];
```

api.php

```
Route::get("/news/{page}", [NewsController::class, 'getMainNews']);
Route::get("/category-news/{permalink}/{page}", [NewsController::class, 'getCategoryNews']);
Route::get("/categories", [NewsController::class, 'getCategories'])->middleware([\Illuminate\Http\Middleware\HandleCors::class]);
Route::get('/provider-news/{permalink}/{page}', [NewsController::class, 'getProviderNews']);
```

Route::get('/single-news/{permalink}', [NewsController::class, 'getSingleNews']);

You can see the classic CORS error in the attachment.

[image]

How can I solve this problem.

Please note that I'm new to Laravel.

Comment: `/public/api/categories/` and `api/*` don't appear to match.

Comment: You mean that I need to put also "public/". I tried but not working.